# Is it possible to access a DataGridRow from its DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

At runtime, I would like to modify the layout (like the backgroundcolour) of a row in a DataGrid.

I was expecting something like:

```
DataGrid dg = ...;
...
dg.Rows[i].BackGround = ...;
```

To my surprise, this seems not to be possible, it goes even further:

When I hover over the word `DataGrid` and I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, I arrive at the file "*C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\MetadataAsSource......\DataGrid.cs*", which mentions all fields and properties of the `DataGrid` object, but there seems not to be any `DataGridRow` present. I have seen solutions for this issue on the internet, but they are based on the design, configuring the `DataGrid` in the XAML ... (I'm finding this quite complicated).

As this is my first WPF application, I suppose my way of thinking to be in contradiction with WPF policy, and that's my question:

> Apparently, modifying a part of a UI control at runtime, based on user interaction, described in simple methods (not events), seems to violate WPF policy.
> Can anyone explain me why?

**Edit, after some tests**

I've been testing the following piece of code, as mentioned in [BionicCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141792/bioniccode)'s answer:

```
DataGridRow row = dg_Areas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) 
                  as DataGridRow;
```

Although this piece of code looks fine (and indeed it finds the row I'm referring to), there seems to be a big problem with that code, which can be best shown using this example:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < dataSet.Tables["Areas"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = dg_Areas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) 
                      as DataGridRow;
    row.Background = Brushes.White;
```

(It's the intention to give each row a white background, which can be coloured differently if a condition is met)

This code generates a `NullPointerException` when `i` equals 12, which can be demonstrated using this application's screenshot:

[image]

(As you can see, the row, corresponding with `i` 12, is not visible on screen. I've done multiple tests and they all yield the same result.)

So the proposed way of working only works with rows, which are actually visible on screen. Is there a way to access the row of a `DataGrid`, even when it's not immediately visible on screen?

Apparently, in order to cope with that, the following setting must be done in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_Areas" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ...
```

Comment: Just like HTML you specify styles instead of modifying properties directly. Just like HTML, a grid may be using virtualization to display 1K rows of data without actually rendering 950 invisible rows. The same configuration you see in XAML can be done in code as well, using the same types and properties. You can create conditional styles, alternate rows etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` is an `ItemsControl`. `ItemsControl` generates an item container for each data item. The default container for e.g. `ListBox` is `ListBoxItem`. For the `DataGrid` it's the `DataGridRow`.

To get the container of an item or by the item's index, you need to use the API of the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as DataGridRow;
DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
```

The item (referenced by instance or its index) must be realized, when UI virtualization is enabled. When Ui virtualization is enabled, items are only guaranteed to be realized when the item is inside the viewport of the virtualizing control's scroll viewer.

This will be always the case when you are handling the `Selector.SelectedItem` of the `ItemsControl` (when the selection was triggered by UI user interaction).

For random access while UI vurtualization is enabled, you can realize the required virtualized container by scrolling the item model programmatically into view:

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
```

However, the recommended approach is to avoid dealing with item containers directly. It's very rarily necessary to do so. Instead, you should handle the data model. This eliminates to deal withUI details like UI virtualization and other UI related issues.

Preferably use XAML to handle container rendering details like Background color or layout details in genetal. You have styles, templates and triggers as tools to dynamically manipulate item containers.

For example, if you need to toggle the containers `Background` based on a condition, you would define a trigger ([examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.triggerbase?view=net-5.0#examples)) in XAML.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code seems not to work in some cases. I've edited my question accordingly. Do you have a solution for those cases?

Comment: I found a way to solve the NullPointerException, and modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Disabling virtualization is not recommended. Why does scrolling the required item into view does not work for you?

Comment: I just prefer the row background to be adapted, even if it is just in background. In case I want to see the modified background, I might simply do the scrolling manually at that moment.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand the problem. Referring to your given example you simply must scroll the 12th item into the view. This will force the container to be generated so that you can get it using the ItemContainerGenerator.

Comment: @Dominique I have read your updated question and can tell you that you did not implement my example. I clearly said *"For random access while UI vurtualization is enabled, you can realize the required virtualized container by scrolling the item model programmatically into view:"*. Then I gave an example that scrolls the item of interest into view **BEFORE** retrieving the container. You should read the complete answer and not the first part.

Comment: Now that you have added more information about what you are actually doing, I can tell you that you are doing it wrong. You should define triggers in XAML that set the row's background based on a condition. This would also eliminate the need to care about generated items. It's much easier.

Comment: It's not wise to avoid XAML. You will most definitely find yourself in complicated or complex situiations like this. You have to deal with some WPF details that may are too much for beginners. This is intermediate stuff. If you would have learned some XAML basics you wouldn't be here asking that question. WPF is a very complex framework. You really don't do yourself a favor by dodging to learn the basics. It will always come back to haunt you.

Comment: WPF is designed around concepts like XAML to design the GUI and data binding (MVVM to be precise). That's why there is no escape to learn XAML. As an alternative, you are left to write tons of complicated C# that require much deeper knowledge of how WPF (and certain controls) works. This code will be horrible to read and therefore not easy to maintain. Markup languages like XAML are very popular for GUI design for a very good reason. If you really don't want to learn it, consider switching to WinForms. Every modern application framework uses a markup language to designj the GUI.